# how to install Spreadsheet::WriteExcel module for Active perl?

Tags: perl

hi i have been using strawberry perl and am facing the same problem i am unable to install Spreadsheet::WriteExcel module with my strawberry perl can any one suggest some solution

i have tried active perl with some suggestions given in Stackoverflow even though its showing as downloading failed

i have used

```
      C:\> ppm install Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
```

for active perl it says cant find any packages that support Spreadsheet::WriteExcel.

i have tried based on instructions given in following link even though am unable to do it 
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-            2.37/docs/WriteExcel_Install.html
what can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ppm install Spreadsheet-WriteExcel` - the 2 colons are probably the source of the issue.

HTH!
TheJester1977

Answer (score 1):

in the cmd console type

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install Spreadsheet::WriteExcel"
```

Hint Alt, E , P in English Win pastes the text to the console from the clipboard ...